# Editing an own answer shall I delete me first explanation?

Tags: discussion

How to edit an answer?

a) Just writing **Edit** and add the new or corrected information

b) Delete the earlier part and the first reflections?

c) Just post a second answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is none of those, unless something was dramatically wrong with your first draft.

Just edit your post. You can add a reason in the edit reason box, and people can see the revision history.

Comment: If something were dramatically wrong (misinterpreted the question, etc.), would it be a good idea to put "Edit:" so that future viewers know what the comments on the answer are referring to? Or should the now-sourceless comments be flagged as "no longer relevant"?

Comment: When comments have led to improvements on a post, they should be flagged as no longer relevant so we can delete then